# How rotation affects geodesics on earth (Gravity Probe B)?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, rotational-dynamics, earth, geodesics

What situation gives Gravity Probe B or frame-dragging after 16 million years ?

If light is following space-time geodesic and light is bent in Kerr metric (instead of straight in Schwarzschild)

After 16 million years of 0.000011 degree/year wouldn't be the star situated in earth direction (at all measurement on each stellar rotations of earth)?

Answer (score 0):

The direction to the star appears to be the direction from which light approaches. Light comes to earth at high speed. It doesn't spend 16 million years near earth. So it is only deflected an infinitesimal amount by frame dragging.

Gravity Probe B spends all its time near earth. Its position would be affected over 16 million years.

Comment: The frame dragging of 0.000011 degree/year is the drag between the ground and the satellite, no? Then this drag after 16 million years would be 180 degree between ground and satellite, no?

Comment: I haven't checked your numbers. But this means the satellite would be 180 degrees from where it would have been without frame dragging.

Comment: "But this means the satellite would be 180 degrees from where it would have been without frame dragging." Relative to earth, that can't be because without frame dragging it would mean space is not normal.